# Corda query throws "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: object is not an instance of declaring class"

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, corda, fasterxml

I'm developing cordapp using the example-cordapp project as a reference. I've been able to commit a transaction to the ledger and even run querias on the node to see if it's really there. However, when I try to run query from my Spring Boot application, I get this error.

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request 
processing failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: JSON mapping problem: 
java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList[0]->net.corda.core.contracts.StateAndRef["state"]- 
>net.corda.core.contracts.TransactionState["data"]- 
>com.mypackage.states.MyState["party"]; nested exception is 
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: object is not an instance of declaring class 
(through reference chain: java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList[0]- 
>net.corda.core.contracts.StateAndRef["state"]->net.corda.core.contracts.TransactionState["data"]- 
>com.mypackage.states.MyState["party"])] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~ 
[na:1.8.0_251]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
```

Here's the request code

```
 @GetMapping(value = [ "/api/v1/states" ], produces = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])
fun getMyIOUs(): ResponseEntity<List<StateAndRef<MyState>>>  {
    val myStates = proxy.vaultQueryBy<MyState>().states
    return ResponseEntity.ok(myStates)
}
```

And here's the state code

```
@BelongsToContract(com.sentinel.contract.SharingInformationContract::class)
class SharingInformationState(
    val party: Party,
    val dataOwnerId: Long,
    val dataBuyerId: Long,
    override val linearId: UniqueIdentifier = UniqueIdentifier()) : LinearState, QueryableState {

override val participants: List<AbstractParty> = listOf(party)


override fun generateMappedObject(schema: MappedSchema): PersistentState {
    return when (schema) {
        SharingInformationSchemaV1 -> SharingInformationSchemaV1.PersistentSharingInformation(
                party,
                dataOwnerId,
                dataBuyerId,
                linearId.id
        )
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unrecognised schema $schema")
    }
}

override fun supportedSchemas(): Iterable<MappedSchema> = listOf(SharingInformationSchemaV1)
```

}

There's little information about this issue on the internet. Some suggest it is connected to the classpath, that something is duplicated there, but I don't know how to check. Also, this error isn't connected to the Party type. I've tried to add `@JsonIgnore` on a party, but then it throws on the other field. Persistence of this field in mapping schema also doesn't matter. I've tried persisting and not persisting, it changes nothing. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is because you are missing Corda Jackson support library which is required to convert Corda objects to json.

Add this to your dependencies in the build.gradle

```
compile "net.corda:corda-jackson:$corda_release_version"
```

https://github.com/corda/samples-java/blob/master/Advanced/auction-cordapp/client/build.gradle#L19

Also, make sure you have a `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` bean configured.

@Bean

```
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(){
    ObjectMapper mapper =  JacksonSupport.createDefaultMapper(partyAProxy());
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    converter.setObjectMapper(mapper);
    return converter;
}
```

https://github.com/corda/samples-java/blob/master/Advanced/auction-cordapp/client/src/main/java/net/corda/samples/client/AppConfig.java#L48

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I really missed that bean. Although, unfortunately, it still doesn't work. I work on IDEA 2019 with Kotlin plugin version 1.3.71. Can it cause the problem? As far as I read Corda depends on 1.2.71

Comment: Not really sure if the Kotlin plugin could be a problem. You may try to see if this works for you: https://github.com/corda/samples-kotlin/tree/master/Advanced/auction-cordapp/client/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/samples/client. This is the kotlin version of the sample I referred in the answer.

Comment: If the above work, you can be sure that Kotlin plugin is not a problem and you may want to take this as a reference to validate your code.

Comment: I decided to check whether I get anything from the node and what I get. So the node returns everything like it should, but for some reason the types which are returned are not recognized as they should be. For example, I tried to cast the received states and got this : *java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mypackage.states.SharingInformationState cannot be cast to com.mypackagel.states.SharingInformationState*

Comment: in the example you provided, the version of Kotlin is 1.2.71. Plugin aside, the version is in gradle. cordapp-example works with latest plugin, but with a version of 1.2.71

Answer (score 0):

The Exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class` is something that happens if a method is called by reflection on an object which is of the wrong type.

In conjunction with jackson that may happen because a generic is lying to you. Here is an example:

```kotlin
class A (val x: String)
class B (val y: String)
class C (val z: List<A>)

ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(C(listOf(B("x")) as List<A>))
```

This causes a compile warning, but it compiles and initially runs because of type erasure. However we forcefully injected a `List<B>` in a place where actually a `List<A>` is expected. While type erasure does remove quite a bit of information, it does not do so completely. Reflection can still be used to determine that `C.z` is actually of type `List<A>`. Jackson uses this information and tries to serialize an object of type `A` but instead finds an object of type `B` in the list and fails with the given message.

Check that your data structure actually contains the types that you expect!